# Request.Querystring["id"] is not working in aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing the 'id' in the url as

```
<a href="Single Product.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Category_type_ID")%>"><%#  Eval("Category_type_Name") %></a>
```

'id' is visible in the url of target page but when I try to fetch the id like follows:

```
string val = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

it does not work.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work" ? Error message ? val is empty ?

Comment: can you provide the error and url ?

Comment: val is empty. it shows nothing

Comment: http://localhost:6040/Website/Single%20Product.aspx?id=3

Comment: and also provide the code in which you are handling the `Request.QueryString["id"]`

Comment: because without code it will be hard to trace the problem

Comment: I am using this line in the page load and just connecting with my database after that,

Comment: string val=Request.QueryString["id"];

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                conn.Open();
               
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tbl_Category_Type where Category_type_ID="+val+"", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                
            }

Comment: Hope you wrote this code in the page **"Single Product.aspx.cs"** file.. And is space allowed in page names? Did you try removing that space in the file name?

Comment: space is allowed. even removing the space in file name didn't solve the issue

Comment: Open the page where this link is visible in google chrome. Right click the link and click inspect. It will show you the actual value getting populated for Category_type_ID inside the anchor tag. Do you really see some integer value there?

Comment: what about fire fox?

Comment: I added a listview control in aspx page and then bind the database data using same code. it solved my problem,

Comment: Don't write your sql commands like that - you are introducing a SQL injection security vulnerability. Use parameters with the query.

Comment: @Iqra Any browser should do for that matter as long as you are able to inspect the HTML of the HTML element.

Comment: i got it. thankyou @RBT

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='Single Product.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Category_type_ID")%>'><%#  Eval("Category_type_Name") %></a>
```

Replace with "" to ''. 
try this code

Comment: even changing " to ' is not solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the url `localhost:6040/Website/Single%20Product.aspx?id=3`
the code must be implemented in `Single Product.cs` like

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string test = Request.QueryString["id"];
        }
```

because whenever the url redirects to `single product.aspx` first of all it executes the code in the `page load` of `Single Product.cs`. You can place a break point to verify the value of `id`.

Comment: I am already using this in the page load of my  target page. I have tried to fetch 'id' in a Textbox also, but it is not visible even in Textbox.

Comment: did you place break point in the pageload of the target page's code?

Answer (score 0):

The mention code should work,

if you are using a Gridview, you can use a template field to get the code run, this is working as I have tried.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="Default2.aspx?id=<%# Eval("CountryId") %>" ><%# Eval("CountyName") %></a>                           
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

please share your .aspx page code where and how you actually consume the values.

Comment: <div class="product-inner">
                                    <h2 class="product-name"><%# Eval("Category_type_Name") %></h2>
                                    <div class="product-inner-price">
                                        <ins><%# Eval("Weight") %></ins>
                                    </div>      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                                                <h2>Product Description</h2>  
                                              <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
                                            </div>